# Cubic Root Algorithm in O(n) and O(log n) time

Tags: c++, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

How would I go about calculating the cubic root in O(n) time and O(log n) time? The algorithm that has a time complexity of O(log n) I would would binary search (I'm guessing)? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: The more usual notation is O(n), not T(n).    In any event, it depends on the type of `n`, what operations the algorithm uses, and the cost of those operations.  But, yes, assuming multiplications and divisions can be performed in constant time,  and the time for additions is insignificant in comparison with the time for multiplication or division, a binary search can find a cube root with O(log(n)) complexity.

Comment: What does "n" mean here? Are you looking for the cubic root of an integer (if it exists)?

Comment: You mean 3 is the cubic root of 27. If n=60, what do you expect?

Comment: @Olivier Correct. Then it should output would be 3.9148676412

Comment: you can calculate in `O(1)` using `std::pow(n, 1/3)`, there is standart function to calculate cubic root since C++11 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cbrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For O(n) you can just iterate from 0 to n, checking if the number is the cubic root you're looking for. (This only works with integers)

```cpp
int cubic(int n){
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
       if(i*i*i==n)
           return i;
    return -1; // cubic root doesn't exist.
}
```

For O(logn) you can do a binary search from 0 to n:

```cpp
double error=0.00000001;
double cubic(double n){
    double l=0, r=n, m=(r+l)/2;
    while (abs(n-m*m*m)>error){ // if difference between m^3 and n is not satisfactory
        m=(r+l)/2;
        if(m*m*m<n) // if m^3 < n, then the root is definitely greater then m, so we move the left border
            l=m;
        else // otherwise, move the right border
            r=m;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using [Newton–Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)? If you're looking for a cubic root of `N` than you're essentially looking at a root of `f(x) = x^3 - N`. The convergence of Newton's method is quadratic in time and the complexity would be `O(log(n))`.

EDIT: More precisely, as described [here](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Computational_complexity) it has a complexity of `O(log(n)F(n))` where `F(n)` is the cost of calculating the "update" with `n`-digit precision.